# Is there any way to change a non-player entity's data in Minecraft 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need this rather old version for an experiment which likely doesn't work in newer versions.
Unfortunately, the `/entitydata` command was added in 1.8 (and the `/data` being even newer.
**Is there any way to change an entity's data after it spawns?**

Comment: Note that the `@e` selector was also added in 1.8, so you would also have to find some non-obvious way of deciding what entity's data to modify

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using mods there is an [in game NBT editor](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/nbtedit) mod. Simply look at the entity (or tile entity like chests/spawners) and use the `/nbtedit` command. It brings up a nice little GUI for you to work with and multiple save states for NBT data if you need to paste them. You can also edit yourself with `/nbtedit me`.

**Warning: this mod can and will corrupt things if you don't know what you're doing! Make a backup of your world if it's even remotely important!**

[Alternate github link for 1.7.10](https://github.com/DavidGoldman/NBTEdit)

Comment: Second link is because I can't actually access them from work. Only Google cache copies.

Comment: Also, on the off chance that neither of those links work or you can't get a functioning 1.7.10 jar from them I can upload a new one after work (in roughly 6 hours)